# How to obtain pixels along math function?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an OpenCV image, a math function like x^2 and a set of discrete calculated points along this function. How do I obtain the pixels of the underlying discrete points?  Since the calculated points are of type `cv::Point2d()` e.g. (4.2823, 7.2442), I dont know how to map referring pixels to it.

Not quite sure if I was clear enough, just let me know. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the range of the function to be drawn (e.g. x[-5, 5], y[-25,25], with fxmin = -5 and fymin=-25) to the coordinates of the image. Assuming the leftmost and lowermost coordinate of the image is xLeftImg = 0, yLowImg = img.ySize()-1, then the calculation would be

```
imgpos_x = (point2d.x-fx_min)/(fxmax-fxmin)*img.size().width;
imgpos_y = img.size().height-(point2d.y-fy_min)/(fymax-fymin)*img.size().height;
```